# How do I get the built-in tag "url" to work?

Tags: google-app-engine, django-templates

Does anybody know how I can get built-in Django tag [`url`](http://www.djangoproject.com/documentation/0.96/templates/#url) to work in the wrapped template renderer in google-app-engine?
It fails to create a "nice" url because it expects Django style url mappings, and since I'm using `webapp.WSGIApplication` I understand how it can be difficult for it to work. Basically I want to know if there is an alternative that will work with google-app-engine style url mappings.

Thanks in advance for any input.

Comment: What do you mean by 'google-app-engine style' mappings? As far as I know, if you are using `webapp.WSGIApplication`, your URLs can look anyway that you want them to.

Comment: @Adam Crossland, I mean in Django your url mappings are like `(regex, module.func)`. What I call google-app-engine style is a mapping like `(regex, Class)`, where Class inherits webapp.RequestHandler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible - that function depends on using Django's routing system, which webapp doesn't. More to the point, webapp doesn't provide a reverse-mapping function at all.

Comment: Alright, I didn't think so. How would I go about writing my own custom "tag" for that? I could access the gae mappings and do some magic on the matching on the regex for a given class right?

Comment: Don't worry, your answer is good enough. I'll figure out how to make my own.

Comment: As I mentioned, webapp doesn't provide reverse mappings, so this isn't possible. Unless you use another framework - webapp2 _does_ provide reverse mappings: http://code.google.com/p/webapp-improved/